# error 1048. column cannot be null in Mysql lookup table-something missing?

Tags: mysql, lookup-tables

I want to add data to a lookup table

`locations_borrowers` (id_location_borrower (PK), id_borrower (FK), id_location (FK))

from 3 different tables:

- `borrowers` (id_borrower (PK), forename, surname)
- `locations` (id_location (PK), street, town)
- `all_proto` (borrower_forename, borrower_surname, street, town, occupation, telephone)

I wrote the following:

```
INSERT INTO schema.locations_borrowers (id_borrower, id_location)
SELECT borrowers.id_borrower, locations.id_location FROM borrowers JOIN schema.all_proto
ON borrowers.forename = all_proto.borrower_forename AND borrowers.surname = all_proto.borrower_surname 
LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.street = all_proto.street AND locations.town = all_proto.town;
```

I got an 1048 error, what is wrong?

Comment: This issue has already been discussed
[in my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181916/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-class-code-cannot-be-null/46408903#46408903) early

Comment: This issue has already been discussed
[in my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408903/5871395) early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### MySQL :: Error: 1048 Column cannot be null for Insert

Since you are using `LEFT JOIN` the column `locations.id_location` may be null.

This should always be `INNER JOIN` since you are expecting both values to be `NOT NULL`. (If not the table is not making any sense, no?)

Comment: I just put the `INNER JOIN` but a 1054 error come up: Unknown column 'Id_location' in 'field list'

Comment: Check for typos. Either in your table or in your query. Is 'id_location' consistently the same everywhere?

Comment: yes I had a little typo. However it now runs the command without errors but  nothing happened: 0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Add some data from the tables that you expect to match. So we can help you take a look at it.

Comment: Or maybe better close this and open a new question containing all information of the current situation. Else this may lead us to far

Comment: Thanks! I just opened a new question "Correct command no result. 0 row(s) affected Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0"

Comment: Still the problem you encountered appear to be fixed so you can indicate this as well for further readers.