# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'class_code' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

```
My controller:
$class = new joinclass();
$class -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$class -> class_code = $request['class_code'];
$class -> save();
```

`Class_code` is another table column name. It's not primary key or foreign key.

Comment: dd($request['class_code'], it should be null, your database column class_code does not allow that, maybe do a $class->class_code = $request->input('class_code', '');

Comment: Yes its show no error. But i don't get class_code data in my database.

Comment: Check your form, seems like you are not passing value correctly into $request->input('class_code')

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Your field `"class_code"` contain "nothing" (null) and Your MySQL server is running in "strict" mode.
As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, which is exactly the cause of your headache.

To change your server's mode, edit your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini` if you're running Windows) and set the mode to:

```
sql-mode=""
```

Then you must restart your mysql server like this:

```
service mysql reload
```

Or directly throw init.d process:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql reload
```

Hope it will help you.